# Winforms Visibility issues on Dynamically Loaded UserControls?

Tags: winforms

So I have a program that dynamically loads in usercontrols depending on certain criteria, The problem I'm having is that my validation is only *truly* working on the first textbox loaded.

The following code is ran for each usercontrol loaded:

```
        Try
            TextBox = DirectCast(flpRepeatConts.Controls(Count).Controls("tbAnswerText"), Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBox) ' Control(1) = TextBox Answer
            LabelAnsID = DirectCast(flpRepeatConts.Controls(Count).Controls("lblQID"), RadLabel)
            LabelMinHolder = DirectCast(flpRepeatConts.Controls(Count).Controls("lblMinTextHolder"), RadLabel)
            lblValidationText = DirectCast(flpRepeatConts.Controls(Count).Controls("lblValidationText"), RadLabel)

            If TextBox.Text.Length >= LabelMinHolder.Text And TextBox.Text.Length <= TextBox.MaxLength Then
                'Good to go.
                lblValidationText.Visible = False
            Else
                'Too little/not enough text
                If LabelMinHolder.Text = TextBox.MaxLength Then
                    lblValidationText.Text = String.Format("Text must be exactly {0} Characters! ({1} of {0})", LabelMinHolder.Text, TextBox.Text.Length)
                Else
                    lblValidationText.Text = String.Format("Text must be between {0} and {1} Characters!", LabelMinHolder.Text, TextBox.MaxLength)
                End If
                inError = True
                lblValidationText.Visible = True
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Exception Handling Here
        End Try

        Count += 1
```

**The true issue here is that labels past the first one will never show (unless there's atleast one character in its respective textbox, in which case the error message does show).** I'm stumped and was hoping another set of eyes would see something I don't. **I've set breakpoints and stepped through this and the text and visibility *are* in fact being set, they just don't take effect.**

Comment: I understand your problem completely.  There's not enough code here to determine the cause.  Various issues I've been able to find are typically ... cross-thread ... control is not physically located where you are expecting it ... referencing the wrong control ... references are null (you didn't actually get the control) ... based on those usual problems ... I'd say your most likely not getting the control and the exception condition is running

Comment: Standard bug in "dynamically loaded" controls code is to not give the control the proper size, location or Z-order.  Causing parts of the control to get overlapped, you'll only notice by not seeing what you expected to see.  Next standard bug is to use try/catch-em-all in code that is *very* likely to throw an exception.  Like this code, none of it should ever fail and the try/catch can only hide programming mistakes.

Comment: I set a breakpoint inside the Catch and it wasn't hit once. Beyond that, I set another breakpoint further down in the code, and added a watch to all three of my textboxes that were currently loaded and all of them had the correct error message and were set to visible = true. I don't think this is a location issue as the labels appear just fine when I enter a character in the text box. I'm more so unsure as to why the 1 character even matters... Further inspection shows that If I run it with a character, then empty the textbox and run again... The label is shown correctly.